# trouble accessing a struct pointer from another object

Tags: python, cython

#### foo.h

```
typedef int bar;
typedef struct _foo
{
    bar* b;
} foo;
extern foo* foo_new();
extern bar* foo_bar_new(foo* f);
```

#### foo.pxd

```
cdef extern from "foo.h":
    ctypedef int bar;
    ctypedef struct foo:
        bar* b
    foo* foo_new();
    bar* foo_bar_new(foo* f);
```

#### foo.pyx

```
from foo cimport *

cdef class Foo:
    cdef foo* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._ptr = foo_new()

cdef class Bar:
    cdef bar* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self, f):
        self._ptr = foo_bar_new(f._ptr)   # error
                                ^
foo.pyx:11:33: Cannot convert Python object to 'foo *'
```

`cython foo.pyx` throws an error at the marked line.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Changing `_ptr` in `Foo` to `cpdef` results in the same error.

== Update ==
I changed *foo.pyx* to the following and it works.

```
from foo cimport *

cdef class Foo:
    cdef foo* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._ptr = foo_new()

    def new_bar(self):
        cdef bar* b
        b = foo_bar_new(self._ptr)
        tmp = Bar()
        tmp._set(b)
        return tmp

cdef class Bar:
    cdef bar* _ptr
    cdef _set(self, bar* bptr):
        self._ptr = bptr

    def get(self):
        return bar_get(self._ptr)
```

I can do `f=Foo(); b=f.new_bar()` but this doesn't seem ideal to me since I can't create with `Bar(f)` or similar. The problem is that I can't `cdef __cinit__()` since it's a special method. Can't `cdef __init__()` either. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: UPDATE: I managed to get it to compile but it's not ideal. Updates in the original.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing Cython objects with existing C Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686590/initializing-cython-objects-with-existing-c-objects)

Comment: In short, use factory functions that take a `foo*` argument and return a new `Foo` after assigning `Foo._ptr` to the passed in `foo*`. This is needed as `__init__` can only accept python objects, not C types.

Comment: @danny I agree with you about factory functions being an option. However, my reading of the initial question is that OP was trying to pass Cython objects rather than pointers so I don't think your duplicate suggestion quite fits. It fits a bit better with the edit, but I think that's a workround more than what they're trying to do.

Comment: The OP specifically asks how to create Cython object from a pointer, therefore is a duplicate of existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using a modification of the factory function model that seems to work ok.

```
cdef class Bar:
    cdef bar* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._ptr = NULL

    cdef from_ptr(self, bar* ptr):
        self._ptr = ptr
        return self

cdef class Foo:
    cdef foo* _ptr
    def new_bar(self):
        cdef bar* b
        b = foo_bar_new(self._ptr)
        return Bar().from_ptr(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure it knows what type `f` is, at compile time:

```
def __cinit__(self, Foo f):
    self._ptr = foo_bar_new(f._ptr)   # error
```

without doing that it has to assume that `_ptr` is a standard Python attribute lookup (done at runtime), and so will be a standard Python object. If you specify that `f` is a `Foo` then it's able to use the known definition of `_ptr`.

Comment: The above will allow `Bar(Foo())` to be used but not `Bar(f)` where `f` is of type `foo*`.

Comment: Since `__cinit__` is a def function in can only be called with Python types anyway. There isn't a particularly good method for constructing Cython objects directly from c types.

Comment: 'Particularly good' is relevant, though there is a method for doing that which have [talked about before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686590/initializing-cython-objects-with-existing-c-objects).