# wrapping cpp returned typed pointers in cython

Tags: python, c++, pointers, cython, typedef

I am new to cython and I have to wrap a cpp library which, among the rest, defines:

- a class A with its functions
- a typedef A* B
- a class C with a function addA() returning a B

### typedpointers.h

```
typedef objectA * typeB
```

### classes.h

```
class objectA {
    int id;
    objectA(){}
    int get_id() {return id;}
    //...
}
class objectC {
    objectC();
    typeB add_newA(int id){...}
}
```

I've managed to define python classes for A and C but, I have no idea of how to define type B and function addA() since when compiling I get an error saying that type B cannot be converted to a python object:

> Cannot convert 'typeB' to Python object

Any suggestions?

### mywrapper.pyx

```
cdef extern from "classes.h":
    cdef cppclass objectA:        
       objectA() except +
       int get_id() const;

    cdef cppclass objectC:        
        objectC() except +        
        typeB add_newA(int id) const; 

cdef extern from "typedpointers.h": 
    ctypedef objectA* typeB;

    cdef cppclass typeB:
        typeB() except +
```

Comment: Please share your code you tried and the specific error messages.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44686590/initializing-cython-objects-with-existing-c-objects